# Python-UNO bridge: change PDF export options

Tags: python, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I'm trying to generate a PDF from an odt file using Python and the OpenOffice UNO bridge.
It works fine so far, the only problem i'm facing are the export options.
By default, OO is using the existing PDF export settings (the one used the last time, or the default if the first time). But I need set these settings manually, for example "UseTaggedPDF" has to be true.
This is part of the code where i export the PDF:

```
try:
    properties=[]
    p       = PropertyValue()
    p.Name  = "FilterName"
    p.Value = "writer_pdf_Export"
    properties.append(p)
    p       = PropertyValue()
    p.Name  = "UseTaggedPDF"
    p.Value = True
    properties.append(p)


    document.storeToURL(outputUrl, tuple(properties))
finally:
    document.close(True)
```

The PDF is generated but not tagged. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finaly found the solution on http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=70949

```
try:
    # filter data
    fdata = []
    fdata1 = PropertyValue()
    fdata1.Name = "UseTaggedPDF"
    fdata1.Value = True
    fdata.append(fdata1)

    fdata.append(fdata1)

    args = []
    arg1 = PropertyValue()
    arg1.Name = "FilterName"
    arg1.Value = "writer_pdf_Export"
    arg2 = PropertyValue()
    arg2.Name = "FilterData"
    arg2.Value = uno.Any("[]com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue", tuple(fdata) )
    args.append(arg1)
    args.append(arg2)

    document.storeToURL(outputUrl, tuple(args))
finally:
    document.close(True)
```

Comment: (1) You can accept your own answer (2) I encourage to explain how this is the solution.